Como uso una imagen local en tailwind css 3.4.4 en mi proyecto de angular?
Hola estimada comunidad estoy intentando colocar una imagen local en mi proyecto de angular usando tailwind css pero al hacerlo de la siguiente manera no funciona
<div
  class="max-w-md mx-auto bg-white rounded-xl shadow-md overflow-hidden md:max-w-2xl"
>
  <div class="md:flex">
    <div class="md:shrink-0">
      <img
        class="h-48 w-full object-cover md:h-full md:w-48"
        src="/public/lufy.jpeg"
        alt="Modern building architecture"
      />
    </div>
</div>
----------------------------------------------------------------
<div class="bg-yelow-100 my-2">
  <img src="/public/lufy.jpeg" alt="fav" />
</div>
-------------------------------------------------------------------
<div class="bg-[url('/public/lufy.jpeg')]">a</div>

de ninguna manera se muestra la imagen alguien tiene alguna idea de como solucionarlo les comparto mis configuraciones
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "aesst": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/aesst",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kB",
                  "maximumError": "1MB"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kB",
                  "maximumError": "4kB"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "aesst:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "aesst:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Estoy utilizando angular en su version 18 a continuación muestro la version de angular:
Angular CLI: 18.0.6
Node: 20.15.0
Package Manager: npm 10.7.0
OS: darwin arm64

Angular: 
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1800.6 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         18.0.6 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   18.0.6 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          18.0.6 (cli-only)

Mi configuración de tailwind esta asi:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

cabe recalcar que con la url de imágenes de internet si funciona pero la idea es usar necesariamente imagenes locales.


Y estás seguro de que esa ruta es correcta?? Por favor añade una captura con la estructura de carpetas del proyecto

@Benito-B listo he agregado la estructura de mi proyecto para que se entienda  de mejor manera

@DanielPinargo he visto que una práctica común es poner las imágenes en la carpeta assets, tal vez podrías investigarlo y ver si hallas un ejemplo. Yo personalmente no usaría el nombre de un archivo como parte de una clase de un elemento HTML
